# No package 'libffi' found in Homebrew Virtual Environment

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I'm using a homebrew installation of python and getting an error using pip within a [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) environment:

```
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

Homebrew has a formula for libffi (`brew install libffi`), which seemed to be successful.

I can run

```
$ python-config --include
```

which yields:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

So should I "add the directory containing `libffi.pc'"?

`echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` yields an empty string.

[Someone on SO had recommended][3]:

```
Use -I /opt/local/include on the command line
```

or

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include in the environment.
```

Would I add the line:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

to the `~/.bash_profile`?

or possibly `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
brew install libffi

locate libffi.pc
```

(in this case i also had to run the command to build the locate database, for which the code was included in the prompt from locate)

returned `/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/pkgconfig/libffi.pc`

Then *within the virtualenv* ran `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/pkgconfig/` (the path to `libffi.pc`).

Confirmed with `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, which showed the path.

And pip "Successfully installed" the modules!

In case it's useful, this is how I got the virtualenvwrapper environment working:

I have added the following contents to the `~/.bash_profile` as well as `~/.bashrc` files:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

As per [this tutorial](http://philosopherdotdog.blogspot.com/2013/07/install-python-virtualenv.html).

Comment: For a more generic way I use: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix libffi)/lib/pkgconfig/"`

Comment: @DavidBoho underrated comment! Only this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I had to actually use `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/pkgconfig/` to get this to work. Same command, but just the directory instead of the libffi.pc file itself.

Answer (score 1):

On my case I got the next error message when running npm i :

```
node-gyp rebuild

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libffi', required by 'gobject-2.0', not found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --cflags  cairo poppler-qt5' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
I figured out the problem was on exporting the PATH
```

So I ran brew reinstall -s poppler

At the end of the installation you can run the export of the paths

```
If you need to have qt first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find qt you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/qt/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/qt/include"

For pkg-config to find qt you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/pkgconfig"
```

This fixed it for me.

I hope you find it helpfull.